# How to store access token in server side in .net 6

Tags: .net, token, .net-6.0

I am working on a .NET 6 blazor application.
I am using auth0 for authentication.

currently token is generated for each and every request.

How can I store the token and re-use?
for each logged in user one token is enough.

Can I use a file in bin folder and re-use the token. Is it a good idea?